# php date/time cast to datetime or timestamp format for mysql issue

Tags: datetime, casting, timestamp

I'm passing `30/07/2013 23:51` to the following function:

`$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $data)));`

What i get is: `1970-01-01 01:00:00`

What i need to do is to cast the given date to a "datetime" (or better, a "timestamp") format for a mysql field

The date is given in the italian format.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it by hand, unfortunately. This function will work:

```
function date_cast($data)
{

$data = explode(' ', $data);

$time = $data[1];

$date = explode('/', $data[0]);

return $date[1]."/".$date[0]."/".$date[2]." ".$time;
}
```

And then you can just call:

```
$date = date_cast('30/07/2013 23:51');
```

Comment: can't get your function to work, but i will do it manually then...this is so ugly...

Comment: I used http://writecodeonline.com/php/ to test it and it works without a problem. Sorry it didn't work for you.